# How to schedule a google meet and get the meet link in NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, calendar, google-calendar-api

In my project I have to schedule a google meet at a given time between two users whose email id I am having in NodeJS. Can anyone help me regarding this ?

Comment: I thought that when you provide your current script and explain the current issue of your script, it will help users think of the solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 8):

You will need to use [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/nodejs) in order to create a Google Meet, here is a working code example of how to do it.

| Create a Google Meet Event | [<kbd>Run in Fusebit [image]</kbd>](https://api.us-west-1.on.fusebit.io/v1/run/sub-c2eaf0578e7140ca/share/share/edit?integrationId=so-70634200) |
| --- | --- |

```js
// You already have the user emails from your NodeJS app
const attendeesEmails = [
  { 'email': 'user1@example.com' },
  { 'email': 'user2@example.com' }
  ];
const event = {
  summary: 'Coding class',
  location: 'Virtual / Google Meet',
  description: 'Learn how to code with Javascript',
  start: {
    dateTime: '2022-01-18T09:00:00-07:00',
    timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles',
  },
  end: {
    dateTime: '2022-01-18T09:30:00-07:00',
    timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles',
  },
  attendees: attendeesEmails,
  reminders: {
    useDefault: false,
    overrides: [
      { method: 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60 },
      { method: 'popup', 'minutes': 10 },
    ],
  },
  conferenceData: {
    createRequest: {
      conferenceSolutionKey: {
        type: 'hangoutsMeet'
      },
      requestId: 'coding-calendar-demo'
    }
  },
};

const response = await calendar.events.insert({
  calendarId: 'primary',
  resource: event,
  conferenceDataVersion: 1
});

const { config: { data: { summary, location, start, end, attendees } }, data: { conferenceData } } = response;

// Get the Google Meet conference URL in order to join the call
const { uri } = conferenceData.entryPoints[0];
console.log(` Calendar event created: ${summary} at ${location}, from ${start.dateTime} to ${end.dateTime}, attendees:\n${attendees.map(person => ` ${person.email}`).join('\n')} \n  Join conference call link: ${uri}`);
});
```